# Comparing multiple values in Google Sheets with App Script for loops

Tags: arrays, object, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to compare multiple values in a Google Sheet spreadsheet some using for loops in Google App Script. But i would like some advice on the best way to do it.

To explain below...

I have two spreadsheets, A "FOOD" table, and A "FOOD GROUP" table.

I've written a for loop script that goes through the entire FOOD table.

If the key value of both tables matches, the script will update a column from the FOOD table with a column from the FOOD GROUP table.

The script works without issues. But it can only compare one column between the 2 tables at a time. I would like to modify this script so I can compare multiple columns at once, without having to create a for loop for each specified column.

I pasted my code below. I can also provide images of my spreadsheet if you need it.

In any case, I'm new to coding, so any constructive feedback or insight to improve my script will be helpful. I'm happy to answer any questions if anything seems unclear.

```
function FoodGroup_Test() {


  var Data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  var FoodGroupDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("Food Groups") // "FoodGroup" sheet
  var FoodGroupAllValues = FoodGroupDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, FoodGroupDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,FoodGroupDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var FoodGroupDataLastRow = FoodGroupDataSheet.getLastRow();


  var FoodDataSheet = Data.getSheetByName("Food") // "Food" sheet
  var FoodAllValues = FoodDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, FoodDataSheet.getLastRow()-1,FoodDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

 // Object to contain all FoodGroup column values
  var Object = {};


   for(var FO = FoodGroupAllValues.length-1;FO>=0;FO--) // for each row in the "FoodGroup" sheet...
  {

    Object[FoodGroupAllValues[FO][15]] = FoodGroupAllValues[FO][11]; // ...store FoodGroup ID Key value
  }


   for(var F = FoodAllValues.length-1;F>=0;F--) // for each row in the "Food" sheet...
  {  

    var Food_FoodGroupKey = FoodAllValues[F][94]; // Store FoodGroup Key value. 

    // ...if the Food value dont match, update it with FoodGroup's value
      if (Object[Food_FoodGroupKey] != FoodAllValues[F][95])  
      { 
        FoodAllValues[F][95] = Object[Food_FoodGroupKey]; 
      }

  }

  // declare range to place updated values, then set it.
  var FoodDestinationRange = FoodDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, FoodAllValues.length, FoodAllValues[0].length); 

  FoodDestinationRange.setValues(FoodAllValues);


}
```

[FOOD GROUP Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJo9b.png)
[FOOD table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExiTc.png)

Comment: why are you doing this with a script rather than vlookuping the value?

Comment: @J.G. for various reasons actually too many to list them all. But one of the main ones is that I'm using a 3rd party application to enter data in the spreadsheets.  Spreadsheets with external formulas affect the application's performance. Also, from my experience, App Script's performance is more reliable.

Comment: You just need to add a "and" condition. Something like: `Object[Food_FoodGroupKey] != FoodAllValues[F][95] && object2[] != FAllValues[F][86])`

Comment: Hey @Neo, would you mind sharing a copy of your sheet as well? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 added screenshots of my spreadsheet in the post. Hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn't

Comment: @TheMaster thanks for the insight. Your suggestion helped. I basically added all my conditions in the "If" condition and everything updated at once. Much appreciation for your input. I do have one related question, however. Some of the referenced fields are blank spaces. However, when the if-loop runs, it replaces the blank field with "undefined". Any suggestions on how i can write code to avoid it adding "undefined" in these fields?

Comment: It you're getting `undefined`, your loop is probable overshooting the available array length. Can't say much without seeing actual script and log data ( what variable is undefined?  and where?). It's better to ask a new question. However, You can test if a value is undefined using something like `typeof x === "undefined"` then ignore that row. Or `if (x==="")` ignore that row(`continue` or `break`).

Comment: @TheMaster I found a good enough workaround. I just used the following code to replace all the "undefined text. `FoodDataSheet.createTextFinder("undefined").replaceAllWith("");` So i'm all set now. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order for your code to work as expected, you should do the following changes to your code:

1. Update your `if` condition to this one:

```
Object[Food_FoodGroupKey] != FoodAllValues[F][95] && object2[] != FAllValues[F][86])
```

2. In order to avoid the `undefined` problem use the following line of code:

```
FoodDataSheet.createTextFinder("undefined").replaceAllWith("");
```

Comment: thanks. I figured the second part out and had already added it in the code (see previous comments.). I'll add the first part. Do you mind if I ask how the "object2[]" affects the "IF" condition?